# Completely close an OS X application with window close button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I need completely close my application when a user closes the document window using the applications at runtime.

Currently when they click the window, the application stays open and is displaying its menu bar.  I read this article for iOS and to add an entry into the plist file:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/40081/ios4---make-app-not-run-in-background

What is the easiest way for me to close the entire app when a user closes the document window?

Answer (score 55):

Is this a Mac app? If so, have your `NSApp` delegate implement [`applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)application
{
    return YES;
}
```

Using Swift, it would be:

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
     return true
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how that's not the default..  It drives me crazy that all my mac apps stay open.

Comment: same here...I just dont get it... what made Apple guys think that clicking a RED X  actually means "users dont really want to close this app, lets leave it running and hide the User Interface"  thats just stupid IMO.

Comment: @DevCompany: The Mac OS has operated that way since its inception. It operates on an application-centric, rather than window-centric, model. As a long-time Mac user, I'm actually surprised when closing the last window closes the application.

Answer (score 6):

When the button is pressed:

```
[NSApp terminate:self];
```

Comment: Where exactly can I copy and paste this code?  I opened IB and I see NSWindow there...but then what?  Sorry I dont know... :(

Comment: If this is a mac app it should go in your IBAction that is linked to the quit button. If you want the application to terminate when the x is clicked in the top left corner, try the viewDidUnload method.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `NSWindowDelegate` in `YourWindowController.h` file and then add the following method in `YourWindowController.m` file:

```
-(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // You can use either of the following lines:
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];

    // OR
    exit(0);
}
```

You will need to use the NSWindowDelegate for all your windows.