# How to terminate programmatically a MacOS app when clicking on the top left red dot?

Tags: macos, swiftui, terminate

Good Day!

By default when we click on the top left red dot of our window app, the window closes but not the app and the menu bar stays displayed on top.

What I would like to achieve by code is to terminate (close) the app when we click on the red dot... by doing this the menu bar will disapears hence the app is terminated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Completely close an OS X application with window close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233141/completely-close-an-os-x-application-with-window-close-button)

Comment: The 'dot' tag you selected was inappropriate.  Read and know the meanings of tags before selecting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following callback in your app delegate

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    //... other methods here

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to do this because my App was rejected by the Apple Review Team with the following message:  *** "We found that when the user closes the main application window there is no menu item to re-open it.
It would be appropriate for the app to implement a Window menu that lists the main window so it can be reopened, or provide similar functionality in another menu item. macOS Human Interface Guidelines state that "The menu bar always contains a Window menu". *** Because I did not know how to solve this issue I decided to terminate the app when clicking on the red dot to remove the menu...

Comment: This does not work for me on Xcode 14 / Ventura